# Why is SYSDATETIMEOFFSET precision decreased on Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

When I run the query on a local SQL Server 2019 instance, I get values like this:

```
2021-03-24 14:32:32.5811589 -05:00
2021-03-24 14:32:37.8169216 -05:00
2021-03-24 14:32:42.6465055 -05:00
```

When I run the query on an Azure SQL database, I get values like this:

```
2021-03-24 19:31:04.6733333 +00:00
2021-03-24 19:31:15.8300000 +00:00
2021-03-24 19:31:20.4866666 +00:00
```

In the latter, the last 5 digits are always repeating values. The value is less precise (or do I mean less accurate?) when the function runs on Azure SQL. Why is the behavior different?

The documentation for [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says:

> SQL Server obtains the date and time values by using the
> GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() Windows API. The accuracy depends on the
> computer hardware and version of Windows on which the instance of SQL
> Server is running. The precision of this API is fixed at 100
> nanoseconds. The accuracy can be determined by using the
> GetSystemTimeAdjustment() Windows API.

But if the hardware matters, I don't expect I'll be able to know that information for Azure SQL.

I am working around this issue by instead using this sort of query to get a more precise datetimeoffset value:

```
SELECT (SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

For some reason SYSUTCDATETIME doesn't suffer from the "last 5 digits repeat" issue when I run it on Azure SQL. The documentation for [SYSUTCDATETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does say:

> SYSDATETIME and SYSUTCDATETIME have more fractional seconds precision
> than GETDATE and GETUTCDATE.

but it doesn't mention having more precision than SYSDATETIMEOFFSET.

I just want to understand this issue better and know what I precision I can rely upon from SYSDATETIMEOFFSET and SYSUTCDATETIME on Azure SQL.

Comment: What tier are you on?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani "select edition, service_objective from sys.database_service_objectives" returns GeneralPurpose ElasticPool

Comment: Created "suggestion" bug here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/43034130-sysdatetimeoffset-precision-decreased-on-azure-sql

Comment: I upvoted. BTW today I found a list of well known issues that Miscrosoft know and hasn't resolved in years: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/doc-changes-updates-release-notes?tabs=single-database#known-issues . Keep in mind that we live in an imperfect World and the cloud is not the paradise

Comment: Yet again Microsoft has shuttered their feedback system and replaced it with a new one - I manually recreated my issue in it here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sysdatetimeoffset-precision-decreased-on-azure-sql/m-p/2669089#M1150

Comment: I cannot upvote, I can only comment https://snipboard.io/oXKkzf.jpg If I click on Like I can only see who upvoted but I cannot upvote myself.

Comment: Well, something interesting - I tried out the "SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()" query today and it is producing 7 digits of sub-second precision (e.g. 2023-05-23 17:20:19.8273249 +00:00). So the behavior on Azure changed at some point since I asked this question.

Comment: Post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, something interesting - I tried out the "SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()" query today and it is producing 7 digits of sub-second precision (e.g. 2023-05-23 17:20:19.8273249 +00:00). So the behavior on Azure changed at some point since I asked this question.